# I am getting an error while trying to install new React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[image]

This is the error I am getting.

I have tried:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. I also uninstalled and re-installed the entire Node.js package. Still, I keep getting this error.

Also, I am doing this for the very first time (since I am starting to learn React), so please simplify your answer a bit. Thank you.

Comment: seems to be a pretty common issue if you tried to use an older version of create-react-app that was installed globally:  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8085